# Including profiles with spring.profiles.include seems to override instead of include

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to partition configuration properties for several Spring Boot applications. I'm using Spring Boot 1.1.6, and our configuration properties are expressed in YAML in the usual application.yml style. I've created various profiles for common base parameters, common DB parameters, etc. I was trying to use the include feature mentioned in the Spring Boot reference docs, but it seems to work as an override and not an include. I.e. exactly the opposite of what I want. Given the following content in application.yml, I would have expected the property **name** to have the value **bar** when the **bar** profile is active, but instead it gets set to **foo** (from the included profile). I thought the notion of including meant that it was loaded first, and any identically named properties set in the new profile would override those from the included profile. Kind of like if a subclass is shadowing a field from the superclass, any instance of the subclass would reflect the shadowed value. Here's the file:

```
spring:
  profiles: foo
name: foo

--- # New YAML doc starts here

spring:
  profiles: 
    include: foo
  profiles: bar
name: bar
```

If I run this in a test case with the "bar" profile explicitly activated, the **name** property will still be foo:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
SpringApplication app = builder.application();
builder.profiles("bar");
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctxt = app.run();
String name = ctxt.getEnvironment().getProperty("name"); // Is always "foo" much to my surprise
```

However, if I comment out the include:

```
spring: 
profiles: bar
#  profiles: 
#    include: foo
```

and activate the two profiles explicitly in my code:

```
builder.profiles("foo", "bar");
```

Then it works as I would expect, and the **name** property is set to **bar**. The main reason I would rather handle the includes in the YAML files is that it's less impact on my actual code, and I can manage all profile inclusion in one place. With the other approach, I'd have to search for profile strings and possible @Profile annotations in my entire project if I were to ever rename the profiles. That's definitely more error prone. I think a more flexible solution would be to explicitly be able to express whether or not the included profile overrides the sub profile values or not. Maybe something like:

```
spring:
  profiles: bar
  profiles:
    include: foo
      override: false
```

Maybe I'm just missing something here. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: The function of `spring.profiles.include` is to affect the `Environment.getActiveProfiles()` so that's how you should test the outcome. You appear to be testing with a property key that is present in both profiles (the last one to be applied wins, and it's probably "bar", since that comes last in the YAML).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dave. This is the first time I've heard it explained this way. Reading the Spring Boot reference documentation, this certainly isn't clear (at least not to me). I think that section needs to be clarified, ideally with an example. Thanks.

Comment: Contributions always gratefully accepted. I'm not clear yet on what the clarification would be though.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'll try to whip something together in my not so copious spare time :-)
I guess my surprise was that the include I specified actually "shadowed" the values from the profile that specified the include. In my mind I was thinking of it kind of like subclassing and overriding methods in the "subclass" profile. I thought of the include as the base class providing some values, and that the "subclass profile" that included it, would override/shadow  property values provided by the "superclass" profile.

Comment: I made the same mistake, at least that's what my tests are showing. Your YAML is incorrect; specifying two "spring:profiles:" YAML nodes causes the second node to overwrite the first. The "bar" in your last snippet is effectively ignored. If there is some way to make a YAML node both a scalar and a collection, I'm not aware of it, and would gladly welcome corrections. The Note in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-adding-active-profiles is a terrible way of saying that "spring.profiles.include" won't work in a profile-specific YAML document.

Comment: To get what you need, you'd need the second doc in this Gist https://gist.github.com/emersonf/11c886e409b1ad7a2b23, which isn't pretty because fragments the profile definition. @DaveSyer, think I should file this as an issue, at least the doc improvement?

Comment: Sure. Let'f fix the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following for **foo** to include but override **bar**, seems to be working for my solution

```
spring:
    profiles:
        include: bar
        active: foo,bar
```

*edit:* please mind, that it's a "hack", not officially supported and it's for 2016 version

Comment: Nice @dpedro! I hadn't thought of explicitly setting several profiles as active like that. That solved my problem.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano it's possible. Note, that there might have been changes in Spring Boot and this solution (hack, really) is for version from 2 years ago

Comment: include and active both supports multiple values. properties present in Last one overrides for the keys present in previous ones. Usually these kind of informations are missing in spring.io documentation.

Comment: This "workaround" no longer seems applicable as of (at the very least, likely earlier) Spring Boot `2.3.7.RELEASE`.  In my case I had to rework my profiles so that my default values are more generic (e.g. `spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://${host}/{$database}`), and are then specifically overridden in the profiles - i.e. the "normal" way. I imagine the groupings could be cleaned up a bit more using profile groups once we switch to `>=2.4.0.RELEASE`. This is obviously unfortunately not applicable in all cases, but should be fine if your infrastructure is clean-ish across the board. YMMV.