# Spring Profile include issue with yaml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, snakeyaml

I'm trying to accomplish when the team sets the websphere profile active that the cloud profile is also activated.

yaml file

```
   ---
    spring:
      application:
        name: kicapp
      output:
        ansi:
          enabled: ALWAYS
      profiles:
        active: local
    #server:
      #context-path: /
      #port: 8080
    #logging:
      #level:
        #org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: local
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: unittest
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: cloud
      test: loaded
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: websphere
        include: cloud
```

When I set `--spring.profiles.active=websphere` I receive the following error

> Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here  in 'reader', line 28,
>   column 12:
>           include: cloud

Comment: Tried to remove the `  ` in front of `include` ?

Comment: @Marged so that `include` is not nested in `profiles`?

Comment: Had a look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985752/including-profiles-with-spring-profiles-include-seems-to-override-instead-of-inc. Which version of Spring do you use  ?

Comment: I was first looking at that post, but that isn't giving me the results I'm looking for. I only want `cloud` when `wesphere` is active. If make chnage the `websphere` profile to ---
spring:
  profiles:
    active: websphere
    include: cloud
  test: websphere . It always loads the `cloud` profile. I'm using spring 4.2 and spring boot 1.3.1

Comment: Try an update to 1.3.2 and check if a classic application.properties does the job

Comment: @Marged already tried that and works of course, but doesn't with the yaml file. Must be a limitation with yaml then?

Comment: Which of the two suggestions ? Ever thought of specifying two profiles ? Would this be viable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103444/discussion-between-ndrone-and-marged).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a restriction with the `SnakeYAML` parser and the way Spring Boot uses it. Since yaml allows multiple distinct documents to be specified in a single file with a `---` separator, the way Spring separates out separate documents is by the `spring.profiles` key, this key is expected to be a simple structure and not a complex structure unfortunately.

A good workaround is actually to split this into multiple files this way:

`application.yaml` with common content,
`application-<profile>` with profile specific extensions, with this structure in place key `spring.profiles.include` will work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Following Biju's answer, if you want to keep the single file with `---` separator and not use separate profile files, you can define the `spring.profiles.include` key as follows :

```
---
spring:
  profiles: currentProfile
  profiles.include: profileToInclude
```

That way it's not a complex structure to parse and both keys exist.