# How to make property file override other included property files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I am using spring boot in my application, and I have a properties file for every profile of the application.
I also have created a shared property file and included to every profile.
it goes like this:
`application-x.properties`
`application-shared.properties`
inside the `application-x.properties` I put this line: `spring.profiles.include=shared` now if I have this line in x profile: `liquibase.enabled=true` while in shared profile: `liquibase.enabled=false`
shared profile will override the original profile and I want the exact opposite I have tried solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985752/including-profiles-with-spring-profiles-include-seems-to-override-instead-of-inc)  but it didn't work.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'application-shared.properties' put the shared properties into 'application.properties'.

Spring will than automatically override properties from 'application.properties' with those of profile specific ones.

See [spring-boot external config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: That does not work if you have properties you don't want to have set in application.properties (e.g. because it's impossible to unset them)