# Spring "spring.profiles.include" overrides

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

My intention is to have two profiles in a Spring Boot application - development and production one. Development profile is meant just to override some variables of production profile (like in-memory database instead of database in the cloud). As I expect some changes to be done to production profile in the future, duplicating variables in development profile doesn't seem to be a solution.

So, in [Spring Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles) I read that `spring.profiles.include` is supposed to only add properties from referenced profile.

> Sometimes, it is useful to have profile-specific properties that **add** to the active profiles rather than replace them. The `spring.profiles.include` property can be used to unconditionally add active profiles.

However, from what I've checked it rather overrides it. So, when having two profiles foo and bar, in separate yaml files:

application-foo.yaml:

```yaml
myproperty: 44
```

application-bar.yaml:

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    include: foo
    active: bar,foo
myproperty: 55
```

And setting `-Dspring.profiles.active=bar` variable in IDE, the runtime value of `myproperty` is 44. That means that `bar`, is overriden with `foo` which was supposed to only add properties, but not to override them. When starting the application, I get:

> The following profiles are active: foo,bar

I added `spring.profiles.active=bar` to `application-bar.yaml` as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699686/1814383), in another question, but it has no effect - there is no difference when property is there or not (I also tried using dash listing instead of comma separated values).

My question is, is it how it is supposed to work (then Spring Reference is misleading)? If so, are there any solutions for that?

Adding a [link](https://github.com/dnldaniel/scratches/tree/master/SpringProfileImport) to the application source code on a GitHub.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We implemented the Spring active profiles in a slightly different way. Let's say the  default properties file, `application.yml`, contains all default values which is same in both production and development environments.

Create separate properties for production and development files named `application-prd.yml` and `application-dev.yml` respectively. These files may contain extra properties or override some of the default properties.

During application startup, we pass the `spring.profiles.active` as an environment variable.  For example,

`-Dspring.profiles.active=prd`

will pick up `application-prd.yml` along with `application.yml`

or

`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

will pick up `application-dev.yml` along with `application.yml`

Comment: Thanks, I think its good enough for my purpose. It still doesnt make developer to be able to override custom property files, so that makes me create additional file (eventually there are application.yaml, application-foo.yaml and application-bar.yaml), but as long as I am able to meet the requirement its fine.

Answer (score 14):

According to the spring boot documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-adding-active-profiles), `spring.profiles.include` is used to add the properties from other profiles. It will add the property from other profiles if the property is not present in active one. But if it is present, then it will overwrite and the last one to be applied wins

> Sometimes, it is useful to have profile-specific properties that **add** to the active profiles rather than replace them. The `spring.profiles.include` property can be used to unconditionally add active profiles.

Comment: I know the link - it mentions "The spring.profiles.include property can be used to unconditionally add active profiles." - this description is ambiguous to me. But thats fine, is there any way then to just import settings from other profile, but not make them override the current one?

Comment: The quote makes no sense, how do you 'unconditionally add' without replacing?  If the property is in both, which one is used?  If it gets added, without conditions, then it is going to replace what's there.  If it doesn't get added if it's already there, then that's a conditional add.

Comment: Ok what the spring docs are talking about is unconditionally adding **profiles**. It's not talking about adding _properties_.  Of course once the profile is added, the usual replacement rules apply about properties that exist in both (last one wins)

Answer (score 11):

Spring Boot 2.4 changes the mechanism for including multiple profiles to use a new [profile groups](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles-groups) feature, rather than using `spring.profiles.include` within the profile-specific document.  This means that your configuration is no longer valid for new versions of Spring Boot, and would need to be changed.

That said, your use case does not seem to be a great fit for profile groups, as it's not really combining two profiles so much as overriding defaults.  Therefore, I recommend using the approach suggested [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373190/1108305) of putting the common and default properties in a shared `application.yaml` file, and only including the environment-specific values & overrides in the profile-specific documents.

**application.yaml**

```yaml
spring:
  myproperty: 44 # Default value
```

**application-bar.yaml**

```yaml
spring:
  myproperty: 55 # Override default
```

Note that Spring Boot supports [multi-document files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-multi-document), so these can be combined into a single `application.yaml` file if desired:

```yaml
spring:
  myproperty: 44 # Default value
---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: bar # These configs apply to the bar profile
spring:
  myproperty: 55 # Override default
```

### Relevant 2.4 Changes

It is no longer possible to use `spring.profiles.include` within a profile-specific document as of Spring Boot 2.4, unless [legacy mode](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide#legacy-mode) is enabled using `spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true`.  Per the 2.4 [Spring Boot Config Data Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide#profile-activation):

> you can still use the spring.profiles.include property, but only in non profile-specific documents.

This approach has been replaced by the [profile groups](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles-groups) feature.  Per the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide#profile-groups):

> As discussed above, it’s no longer possible to use `spring.profiles.include` in a profile-specific document so this file isn’t valid.
>
> Since this use-case is quite common, we’ve tried to provide another way to support it. In Spring Boot 2.4 you can use the [“profile groups”](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles-groups) feature.

This feature is documented in the [Profile Groups](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles-groups) section of the Spring Boot reference guide:

> A profile group allows you to define a logical name for a related group of profiles.
>
> For example, we can create a `production` group that consists of our `proddb` and `prodmq` profiles.
>
> ```yaml
> spring:
>   profiles:
>     group:
>       production:
>       - "proddb"
>       - "prodmq"
> ```
>
> Our application can now be started using `--spring.profiles.active=production` to active the `production`, `proddb` and `prodmq` profiles in one hit.

The migration guide [points out](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide#profile-groups) that the `spring.profile.group` property cannot be used in profile-specific documents.

> The `spring.profile.group` property cannot be used in profile-specific documents.

Comment: Groups are just aliases to the list of profiles. They might give an impression of "documentation" but actually "useless". Just define profiles settings (in `application-$name.yml`) and activate required profiles in `application.yml` with `spring.profiles.active`.

Answer (score 7):

You could add a new profile in the `application-bar.yaml`:

```
spring.profiles.include: foo,foo-override
myproperty: 33

---
spring.profiles: foo-override
myproperty: 55
```

The order is: `33 in bar` overridden by `44 in foo` overridden by `55 in foo-override`.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

- The files: `application-default.yml, application-foo.yml, application-bar.yml`
- `myproperty: default` in application-default.yml
- `myproperty: foo` in application-foo.yml
- `myproperty: bar` in application-bar.yml

I think these 2 use cases of using profiles are a little bit opposite in the meaning:

1. In the most common case (`-Dspring.profiles.active` but no `spring.profiles.include`):

   1. When profile foo or boo are activated the properties from
      application-foo.yml (or application-bar.yml) will add/override the
      ones from application-default.yml.
   2. When profiles foo,bar are activated then properties from bar will add/override those from application-foo.yml and then those from application-default.yml.

   E.g: `-Dspring.profiles.active=foo,bar` the property from application-bar.yml wins (overrides) -> `myproperty: bar`
2. In the second case (`spring.profiles.include` is used)

   1. The properties from the include statement add/overrides the properties from the application-*.yml files which uses `spring.profiles.include`

   I.e.: If `application-boo.yml` contains the `spring.profiles.include=foo` then properties from `application-foo.bar adds/override properties from from application-bar.yml` which add/override those from application-default.yml.

   On the other hand (I suppose) if application-boo.yml includes the `spring.profiles.include=default,foo` then properties from `application-foo.yml` will add/override those from `application-default.yml` which add/overrides those from `application-bar.yml`. So `myproperty: bar`. I wouldn't recommend the usage of `default` in combination with `spring.profiles.include` because this way it mixes the two cases and the override strategy is counterintuitive considering  `application-default.yml` has a special treatment in springboot.

I also admit I am not at all a fan of the `spring.profiles.active` usage in application-*.yml files. I prefer to activate the profiles with system properties (maven included) or env variables. IMO it makes the whole profiles thing clearer to me.

If with my (herein above)reasoning I am on the wrong path please let me know.