# Reference properties from other Spring PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

In Spring I can reference some other property value as variable in a property source

```
base:
  hostName: foo.baa.com

services
  serviceUrl: http://${base.hostName}/fooService
```

This returns `http://foo.baa.com/fooService`. But only if `base.hostName` ist defined in the same file. If it's defined in another `PropertySource` I get `http://${base.hostName}/fooService`.

Can I get this running over several `PropertySource`s?

EDIT: It was just a stupid typo. You can perfectly fine reference variables defined in other PropertySources

Comment: Where is the *other* property file located? is it used by another application or you intend to read the file directly?

Comment: I have to withdraw my question, just had a stupid bug in my code.
You can perfectly fine include variables defined in other PropertySources

Comment: can you mention how you did it, since it was not clear how you intended to include it?

Comment: I have one property file hoding all the `base.*` properties and one holding the `service.*` properties. Both are loaded by different PropertySourcs, but both in the same `ApplicationContext`. And as said: When doing it right, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way of importing another yml into another in Spring...
However, you can make a workaround with the usage of `spring.profiles.include` property. More explanation here: [Spring "spring.profiles.include" overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368086/spring-spring-profiles-include-overrides)