# Spring Boot: Load common config application properties file using bootstrap.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, yaml

In our config server we have following application properties files:

```
helloApp-dev.properties //dev env properties
helloApp-commonConfig.properties //common properties across env
```

The properties are accessible from URI like:

```
https://myapp.abc.com/1234/helloApp-dev.properties
https://myapp.abc.com/1234/helloApp-commonConfig.properties
```

Below is our bootstrap.yml of helloApp application:

```
---
spring:
  application:
    name: helloApp
    
---
spring  
  profiles: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      label: 1234
      name: {spring.application.name}
      uri: https://myapp.abc.com/
```

I am using Spring boot version 2.2.4. The helloApp-dev.properties are loading successfully in application but not commonConfig.

Comment: So basically, the `helloApp-dev.properties` gets picked up because of the profile mentioned in boostrap.yaml, i.e., `profiles: dev`.  If you rename as suggested in an answer below: `helloApp-commonConfig.properties -> helloApp.properties` and keep `helloApp-dev.properties` as it is, then `helloApp.properties` will be shared across all profiles

Comment: Doesn't this answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration in `commonConfig` is not being loaded because you are not indicating to Spring that it should load that profile/config, because you are activating only the `dev` profile - and the configuration for that profile is the one which is being loaded:

```yaml
---
spring  
  profiles: dev
```

In addition to the good solutions proposed by @akozintsov in his/her answer, if you need to include certain common configuration in different environments or profiles, let's say `dev`, `qa` or `prod`, you can use the [`spring.profiles.include`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.profiles.include) configuration property and include, as a comma separated list of values, if using `properties` files, or as a list, if using yaml, the different common profiles and corresponding configurations you need to.

In your example, in `helloApp-dev.properties` you need to include the following information within the rest of your configuration:

```
spring.profiles.include=commonConfig
```

These related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368086/spring-spring-profiles-include-overrides?rq=1) and [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring) could be of help as well.

Answer (score 2):

To load properties file, profiles should match.
You have 2 solutions:

1. Rename *helloApp-commonConfig.properties* -> *helloApp.properties*
2. Use multiple profiles for your application (*dev*, *commonConfig*)